# django query set

Tags: django

I am writing queryset in django. In the first queryset it is working fine. In the second it is giving the error "  cannot resolve xyz into a field .. ..  "

In models.py

```
class XYZ(models.Model):

  id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  addres= models.CharField(max_length=200)

  def __unicode__():
    return self.name

class ASD(models.Model):
  id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  pub = models.ForeignKey(XYZ)
  city= models,CHarField(max_length=200)
```

First queryset:

```
queryset= XYZ.objects.filter(asd__pub____exact='4535344sds3646fhgf7987')
```

Second queryset:

```
queryset= ASD.objects.filter(xyz__id____exact='4535344sds3646fhgf7987')
```

But acccording to [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) it should work.

Comment: Please post your models and actual examples of the code that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `ASD` objects in your `QuerySet` don't have an `xyz` field. Is it possible that you've got a typo or the `Field` name isn't just the lowercase version of the name of the `Model` it is referencing?

Answer (score 0):

In the docs you reference, look closely at the Entry Model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

and how it references the Blog Model:

```
>>> Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__exact='Beatles Blog')
```

`blog` was defined as a field that is a `ForeignKey` to a Blog Model. It is not getting fancy and resolving the foreign model name ("Blog" in this case) to a field value ("blog"); it is simply using the name that you give it. Therefore, you should change your ASD model definition:

```
class ASD(models.Model):
  xyz = models.ForeignKey(XYZ)
```

You have `pub` now, but you are trying to retrieve it by using `xyz`, which is undefined. Also, you have too many underscores in one place; it should read:

```
queryset= ASD.objects.filter(xyz__id__exact='4535344sds3646fhgf7987')
```

Of course, you could change the one query to:

```
queryset= ASD.objects.filter(pub__id__exact='4535344sds3646fhgf7987')
```